# Adding Tag To XML Using Python

Tags: python, xml, web-deployment

```
 98 def add_field(xml):
 99     fields = """
100     <fields>
101         <field>
102             <column/>
103             <description/>
104             <datatype/>
105             <length/>
106         </field>
107         <field>
108             <column/>
109             <description/>
110             <datatype/>
111             <length/>
112         </field>
113     </fields>
114     """
115     #Insert new field into <fields>
116     root = ET.fromstring(fields)
117     new_field = ET.Element("field")
118     field_col = ET.SubElement(new_field, "column")
119     field_des = ET.SubElement(new_field, "description")
120     field_data = ET.SubElement(new_field, "datatype")
121     field_length = ET.SubElement(new_field, "length")
122     root.insert(0, new_field)
```

I am trying to add a new element into an existing XML document. By default, there is two written, however I want to add a third dynamically. The code above does not give me any errors, but on my XML doc nothing changes.

How would I insert a new element into the XML doc?

End result I am looking for:

```
<fields>
    <field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
    <field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
   <field><column /><description /><datatype /><length /></field>
</fields>
```

Answer (score 1):

`root` contains your changes, you can view your change by using ElementTree's [`dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.dump) call. So since we know root contains your changes, you will have to save root by converting into an `ElementTree` and calling [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) on it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fields = """
<fields>
    <field>
        <column/>
        <description/>
        <datatype/>
        <length/>
    </field>
    <field>
        <column/>
        <description/>
        <datatype/>
        <length/>
    </field>
</fields>
"""
#Insert new field into <fields>
root = ET.fromstring(fields)
new_field = ET.Element("field")
field_col = ET.SubElement(new_field, "column")
field_des = ET.SubElement(new_field, "description")
field_data = ET.SubElement(new_field, "datatype")
field_length = ET.SubElement(new_field, "length")
root.insert(0, new_field)

ET.dump(root)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(open('test.xml','w'), encoding='unicode')
```

Will print out and produce a file `test.xml` with the same content:

```
<fields>
    <field><column /><description /><datatype /><length /></field><field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
    <field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
</fields>
```

Edited to match the question that got edited:
Please stop editing your question to be different from the original one.

Anyways, [`insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) takes the index at where you want to slot the new element, so since you want your new element to be in the third slot (2nd index since index starts from 0), just pass it 2 instead of 0:

```
root.insert(2, new_field)
```

Which will produce:

```
<fields>
    <field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
    <field>
        <column />
        <description />
        <datatype />
        <length />
    </field>
<field><column /><description /><datatype /><length /></field></fields>
```

Comment: How would I add the new field under the two old fields. Updated my answer with what the end result I am looking for!

Comment: edited my answer, please note not to edited your original question with follow up question, either create new questions for each one, or ask them all at once. Because this site is for a knowledge based not just a QA.